# Postgresql failover is not working when using multiple hosts in connection string

Tags: postgresql, failover, failovercluster

I am using below python code to test failover,

```
import psycopg2
 
conn = psycopg2.connect(database="ccs_testdb", host="host1,host2", user="postgre_user",                                     
                        password="secret", port="5432", target_session_attrs="read-write")                                  
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("select pg_is_in_recovery(), inet_server_addr()")
row = cur.fetchone()
print("recovery =", row[0])
print("server =", row[1])
```

if host1 goes down then connection is not established with host2 automatically. Does anyone have tried it?

I want to connect to master instance from my application and if master goes down then want to fallback to standby instance which would be host2 in above prog.

Comment: Does the primary go down before you ever run the script, or in the middle of running the script (since the script doesn't loop or sleep, the latter must be hard to arrange)

Comment: I ran script multiple times like before primary instance went down and after that but it didn't switched to connecting secondary

Comment: There is no "switch".  Either it connects to one, or it connects to the other.  So when you run the script after the first host is down, what happens?

Comment: When first instance in list goes down script throws an exception instead of connecting other instance in a list

Comment: *What* exception does it throw?

Comment: Not able to connect to server because target-session-attrs="read-write" will only allow master node to connect to application rather than standby

Comment: Well, sure.  That is what it is there to do.  You need to promote the standby to become the new master, or remove/change the  target-session-attrs spec.

Answer (score 0):

with target_session_attrs="any" it worked. Its connecting to next host in list which is standby